# segmentation fault trying to install go package

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install a go package on Ubuntu 14.04. I followed the instructions and greated a gocode path, but I get a segmentation fault error. See below.

Any ideas?

```
  101  2016-11-14 09:12:05 sudo apt-get install gccgo-go
  102  2016-11-14 09:12:19 go get github.com/atsaki/termeter/cmd/termeter
  103  2016-11-14 09:12:27 go help gopath
  104  2016-11-14 09:12:41 export GOPATH=$HOME/gocode
  105  2016-11-14 09:12:44 mkdir gocode
  106  2016-11-14 09:12:47 go get github.com/atsaki/termeter/cmd/termeter
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Take a look at this link - https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15429